# How to know actives ssh port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have configured in `~/.ssh/config` many port forwarding for VNC with different port for each servers.

Is there a command which can help me to know which port is forwarding to when I open an SSH session ?

Answer (score 18):

If you use the `-v` option to `ssh` it will show you what you are forwarding (but it will show you a bunch of other debug messages, too):

```
ssh -v -L2222:localhost:22 remotehost
```

Will show you:

```
...debug messages...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to remotehost ([10.0.0.23]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:2222 forwarded to remote address localhost:22
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 2222.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 2222.
...debug messages...
```

And then when you are connected to that remote shell you can type a special key sequence:

```
~#
```

which will list the connections like this:

```
The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 7/8 cc -1)
  #4 direct-tcpip: listening port 2222 for localhost port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59742 (t4 r1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 10/10 cc -1)
```

Note, however, that this will only list forwarded ports that are actually being used by another program (in this case I just did `telnet localhost 2222` on my local machine to have it forwarded to `remotehost`.

If you do not have any connections that are currently being forwarded you can still see what your ssh command is listening for locally by using the `netstat` command like this:

```
% netstat -tpln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28995/ssh       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2222                :::*                    LISTEN      28995/ssh
```

The `netstat` command will also probably list other things, but what you want to look for in the output is the `PID/Program` column to look for `ssh` processes, and the `Local Address` column which will show you what ports are being listened to. In this example it is listening on `port 2222` for both IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer,  
  
My goal was to add script in /etc/update-motd.d/ to display Ports redirected to.  
  
But with the ~# command I have only ports redirected on server.  
  
And the goal was to display (part of ssh -v output) :  
Local connections to LOCALHOST:5901 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:5900  
Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5901.  

It seem impossible to display ONLY this 2 lines client side.

Comment: For people coming here in 2020+: `netstat` has been obsoleted in favor of `ss`.

Comment: @ScumCoder Only for Linux.